# How to stop a project dependency being replaced by another project in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multi-project setup and I am defining a project as a dependency in the build.gradle file. But that project is being replaced by another project in the same hierarchy. How do I stop this from happening?

Consider the project structure as:

```
A/B/C1/D/src
A/B/C2/D/src
```

In the build.gradle file inside C1/D, I have defined the project C2/D as a dependency. But then on calling the build task, the dependency C2/D gets replaced by C1/D which is resulting in the following error:

```
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:B:C1:D:compileJava
\--- :B:C1:D:compileJava (*)
```

The build runs fine if I call `:C1:build` but on calling the build task the error appears.

On running the `:B:C1:D:dependencies` I can see the following:

```
+--- project :B:C2:D -> project :B:C1:D (*)
```

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Since the signatures (class names with packages) are the same, gradle takes code from the same project in build task. I would suggest using different names for the code in both projects (for example `impl` infix).

Otherwise you need to have a lot of resources (time and willingness) and use separate classloaders for the resources explicitly.

Comment: The package names are different.